# Stop Images from loading in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview, webview

I have a website that I wish to load in a UIWebView, but it is full of images and takes ages to load. The images are useless, and only serve to reduce the usability on the iPhone. I dont own the website so I cannot change the site's actual code.

The webpage is heavily linked in to the web with ASP.NET and AJAX (needs external files), so i dont think it is possible to have it load an HTML string.

I want to stop the images from loading altogether. So how do i block them? Change the HTML code as its loading somehow, or block images from being loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have 3 thoughts.

1. Use a proxy to filter the HTML
2. Filter the HTML yourself by
   downloading it first
3. Just download the html and load it using a file:// URL. This will most
   likely prevent the image references
   from being resolved - though it will
   leave ugly squares everywhere

Comment: The problem is, its a series of dynamically loaded pages, that have content based on what has been inputted on previous pages. So downloading them and linking them is not an option.

Comment: Then I would use a filtering proxy - its very similar to using an ad blocker on your web browser

Comment: how would I go about implementing that?

Comment: http://www.icab.de/blog/2009/08/18/url-filtering-with-uiwebview-on-the-iphone/ - so I found that, but I am completely phased by it and cannot get it to work...any help?

Answer (score 1):

**The UIWebView delegate approach does not work, you're right ! new answer:**

Right, you need to go one level deeper to catch the `NSURLRequest` coming from the `UIWebView`. The blog you're referring to makes use of the `NSURLCache` and I think this is a good start point:

Did you try to subclass the NSURLCache, and then override the `-(NSURLCacheResponse*) cachedResponseForRequest:(NSURLRequest*) request`

If you want to avoid the request being performed, you need to return something (as an `NSURLCachedResponse`). You can for instance, get an image that is statically defined in your app (maybe an PNG with size 0,0 ).

**If you return `nil`, the request will be performed.**

I'm using this approach to force the `UIWebView` to get populated with a local cache. See my detailled answer about this here :

[How to save the content in UIWebView for faster loading on next launch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343515/how-to-save-the-content-in-uiwebview-for-faster-loading-on-next-launch/2468722#2468722)

---

***Wrong first answer :/***

Add yourself as delegate to the `UIWebView` (`UIWebViewDelegate`).

For each image that the `UIWebView` attempts to load, the delagate gets the following callback invoked :

`-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType`

Just check if the request is related to an image you want to avoid to download. In such a case, just return `NO` to this callback : the image won't be loaded in the `UIWebView`.

**By using this approach, no change is required on server side.**

Comment: I tried that, but it only calls that when the page itself is being loaded. None of the page elements go through there (images, JS, CSS...)

Comment: you're right, I've described another approach in the answer. Cheers.

Comment: your answer is true. My requirement is when any url loading in webview it display only text not images. how can i get IMAGE url in webview request and STOP it

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest another option to try:

using `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` of the WebView's delegate to return  NO when it try to load image.

Comment: your answer is true. My requirement is when any url loading in webview it display only text not images. how can i get IMAGE url in webview request and STOP it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following line of code, whenever you want to stop the webView loading:

```objectivec
[webView stopLoading];
```