# Cache initial webview page in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, caching, memory, webview

My iPhone app has some tabs and main one is showing a webView object that connects to a specific URL and then download its content. However, all is working properly except when user downloads the app for first time through AppStore, then webView is empty because there is no cache data until device will have internet connection.
In order to solve it, I would like to create an initial file cache data for that webView. Possible? How? Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at this thread when you get a chance, it might help -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343515/how-to-save-the-content-in-uiwebview-for-faster-loading-on-next-launch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [use](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIWebPageRequest-a-new-class-for-downloading-complete-webpages) [this](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/substituting-local-data-for-remote.html).