# Search for a string in an if statement with an NSScanner?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsscanner

Is it possible to search for a string in an `if` statement with an `NSScanner`?

I wanted to search through the html of a page and then if there is a certain piece of code, do something and if not, do something else...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use a `NSScanner`.  Just search for a substring in the html as a `NSString`.  Like so:

```
NSString *html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: 
                                         @"document.body.innerHTML"];

if ([html rangeOfString:@"some code here"].location!=NSNotFound) {
    //it exists in the web view
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what to put in place of "incomingtext" because all I have is a UIWebView and a website loaded within that, nothing else...

Comment: I updated the example for you.  You're going to use javascript to extract the html from the web view, and stuff that into a string.  Then you search that NSString for the search term that I have put in as `some code here`.  Let me know if it doesn't work for you, because I actually haven't tested it. :)

Comment: thanks for that - you've been really helpful! :-) Would you be able to look at this question as nobody has properly answered it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508311/nsscanner-working-on-wifi-but-not-3g