# Cocoa: get WebView mainFrame html string

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview, osx-tiger

I'm creating an Mac app that loads some content from a URL in a WebView and then needs to save the content to a file. The content may and may not be HTML. Loading works fine, the problem is to get the content from the WebView. How do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: This would help [How to save the content in UIWebView for faster loading on next launch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343515/how-to-save-the-content-in-uiwebview-for-faster-loading-on-next-launch)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do not know if you use WebView (MacOS) or UIWebVoew (iOS...). I use the following code (in MacOS) which works well for me:

```
WebFrame *frame = [myWebView mainFrame];
WebDataSource *source = [frame dataSource];
NSData *data = [source data];
NSString *str = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
[someTextView setString:str];  // shows the content of myWebView as string
```