# save the complete contents of url in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

In my iPhone app, i want to save a webpage completely and display it later. Some methods were already got when i searched. But any of them is not saving the webpage completely. In some method the images were not saved and in some other methods the text are not displayed in correct font. If anyone has found any new idea please do share it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

reffer to this [How to save the content in UIWebView for faster loading on next launch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343515/how-to-save-the-content-in-uiwebview-for-faster-loading-on-next-launch)