# UIWebView - Issues while storing content for next launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview, nsurl

I am saving the content of `UIWebView` so as to display it on the next launch rather than again loading it. This is what I am doing:

```
NSString *activityesContent = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.outerHTML"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:activityesContent forKey:@"activityesContent"];
```

And for the next launch I am doing this:

```
[_tgWebView loadHTMLString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"activityesContent"] baseURL:nil];
```

This loads the page but without any JavaScript or CSS. It is just a basic HTML content. I know I can load the JavaScript using [**stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString**](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/tag/stringbyevaluatingjavascriptfromstring). But is there somehow I can get all the JavaScript and CSS on the page as I am getting the HTML content, so that I can use it later on?

I also tried with `document.body.parentNode.innerHTML` and `document.documentElement.outerHTML`, but still basic HTML is displayed. The reason for this is, the images, CSS and JavaScript has a server path. I have asked one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28499690/nsurlprotocol-handle-https-request) but it doesn't work for my HTTPS requests.

Neither does this work:

```
NSError *error = nil;
        NSString *activitiesContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:TGURL_ACTIVITIES] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343515/how-to-save-the-content-in-uiwebview-for-faster-loading-on-next-launch/2468722#2468722) solution which is being referred at most of the places. But this gives me a blank page. I even tried to save the contents in a file. When I accessed the source of the page in the file, I found that the path of CSS and JavaScript is relative:

```
<link href="/Content/Sass/style_sass.css?version=1.0.1.09" rel="stylesheet" />  <!-- call style_sass.css file -->
    <link href="/Content/Sass/topbar.css?version=1.0.1.09" rel="stylesheet" />
```

If I try [creating resource folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420925/load-resources-from-relative-path-using-local-html-in-uiwebview), the size of this folder will be huge. Plus there will be a maintenance issue. I have to update the CSS/JavaScript each time there is a change in server CSS/JavaScript.

This is what I am getting:

[image]

And this is what the page should be:

[image]

**Finally what I want:**

What is the best fix for this or is there some other way I can show the entire page (including CSS, JavaScript, images) on the app's further launches ?

Comment: You do it in wrong way, because you newer save any external resources like images, css and js, and there is no any easy way to save them. I can suggest you to use subclass of `NSURLCache` and store entire request from server

Comment: @sage444 : Please provide some idea on implementation of what you are suggesting.

Comment: google around it and check apple's sample for begining   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/URLCache/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: @sage444 : Not useful.

Comment: http://robnapier.net/blog/offline-uiwebview-nsurlprotocol-588 I think this explains whole story

Comment: Hi Nitish - a bit of feedback following my edit. Ordinary technologies such as SQLite, CSS, JavaScript etc. do not need to be rendered either in bold or inline code formatting: they are proper nouns and so either an initial capital or all-caps (for acryonyms) is more than sufficient. Inline code formatting is useful for class names, variables, and console I/O. Hyperlinks also do not also need emboldening - just use the standard stylesheet, to offer some readability and presentational consistency with other questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the UIWebView to load the content initially you can make a direct request and download the full data. When the data is downloaded then you can load the UIWebView with the downloaded content. When using `document.body.outerHTML` you are effectively only getting the body tag.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to use `NSURLProtocol` to observe the HTTP requests for the pages and write them to disk as well. You can then later serve the files from disk rather than reloading them over a HTTP connection also by using `NSURLProtocol`.

Ray Wenderlich has a [great tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/59982/nsurlprotocol-tutorial) on how to use `NSURLProtocol` for basically this purpose.