# How to make UIWebView scroll smoothly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I'm using a `UIWebView` in my app.  When it has many pictures and is still loading, it scrolls jerkily.

How can I make the `UIWebView` scroll smoothly like in Mobile Safari?

Comment: - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView; will tell if data has been loaded successfully in webview.Wait until this delegate hasnot been called to scroll your webView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can cache your images and load them from cache to make the rendering faster. Have a look at the following answers.

1.[How to save the content in UIWebView for faster loading on next launch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343515/how-to-save-the-content-in-uiwebview-for-faster-loading-on-next-launch)

2.[Need content in UIWebView to display quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246420/need-content-in-uiwebview-to-display-quickly)

3.[Substituting local data for remote UIWebView requests](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/substituting-local-data-for-remote.html)

Comment: This is not solution @Vignesh, bcs without image, just make a page which has scrolling. it also lagging (hangs also sometime). only dummy paragraphs even