# Is it possible to cache web pages with a UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, caching, uiwebview

I have an app that contains a UIWebView. I would like the user to be able to view webpages they've previously navigated to when off line. How should I go about making this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to download and cache all the content for each page manually, then recreate them as local pages. There's nothing like Mac OS's .webarchive format on iPhone to save web content.

Comment: Do you know where I should look to find info on this?

Comment: You'll want to take a look at the NSConnection class, and its related classes (NSURL, NSURLConnection, etc).

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345432/is-it-possible-to-cache-resources-loaded-in-an-iphone-uiwebview) is a similar question, but the intent was slightly different.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992348/reading-html-content-from-a-uiwebview/992367#992367) provides detail on loading and caching the text content of a page, but you will still need to grab the other resources of the page (images, etc.) and store them locally like Ben describes.